# PHP / SQL Parse Error

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure what my problem is. On line 4 I keep getting an error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Im assuming its not line 4 but could be. Am I missing something or did I just goof?

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];

        $query = "UPDATE todo_item2
                  SET todo = $_POST['i'], 
                      percent = $_POST['p'], 
                      due_date = $date
                  WHERE todo_id = :id";

        $query2 = "UPDATE todo_category2
                  SET category = $_POST['c']
                  WHERE todo_id = :id";

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $statement1 = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement1 -> execute(array(
        'id' =>$id,
    ));

    $statement2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $statement2 -> execute(array(
        'id' =>$id,
    ));
```

Comment: Why are you preparing the id correctly but not the other fields? Never use incoming user data directly in a sql string.

Comment: Make a testcase please. Problem isolation is fundamental to debugging and you don't appear to have done any before resorting to asking here.

Comment: Placing data from $_POST directly into an SQL query without applying "escaping" it will attempt to execute whatever SQL syntax might be in the $_POST data, which leads to errors like the one you just found but even more importantly it's a huge security vulnerability, often allowing hackers to take over your website. You really need to spend a bit of time researching this, to make absolutely certain you're doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array elements with quoted keys need to use the curly syntax to parse correctly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

The following code should work:

```
    $query = "UPDATE todo_item2
              SET todo = {$_POST['i']}, 
                  percent = {$_POST['p']}, 
                  due_date = $date
              WHERE todo_id = :id";

    $query2 = "UPDATE todo_category2
              SET category = {$_POST['c']}
              WHERE todo_id = :id";
```

Anyway, considering security, it is a terrible idea to use `$_POST` array elements directly inside your SQL query!

Comment: Ok didn't realize that was needed there. Thank you. My data is check before this point and if its not valid it doesn't get to this point, but I will change it to a safer method. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are already using prepared statements you should move the updated values to bound params too -

```
   $query = "UPDATE todo_item2
              SET todo = :todo, 
                  percent = :percent, 
                  due_date = :date
              WHERE todo_id = :id";

    $query2 = "UPDATE todo_category2
              SET category = :category
              WHERE todo_id = :id";

$id = $_GET['id'];

$statement1 = $db->prepare($query);
$statement1 -> execute(array(
    'todo' => $_POST['i']
    'id' =>$id,
    'percent' => $_POST['p'],
    'date' => $date
));

$statement2 = $db->prepare($query2);
$statement2 -> execute(array(
    'id' =>$id,
    'category' => $_POST['c']
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your array access with brackets:

So change `$_POST['i']` to `{$_POST['i']}`:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "UPDATE todo_item2
              SET todo = {$_POST['i']}, 
                  percent = {$_POST['p']}, 
                  due_date = $date
              WHERE todo_id = :id";

$query2 = "UPDATE todo_category2
              SET category = {$_POST['c']}
              WHERE todo_id = :id";

$id = $_GET['id'];

$statement1 = $db->prepare($query);
$statement1 -> execute(array(
    'id' =>$id,
));

$statement2 = $db->prepare($query2);
$statement2 -> execute(array(
    'id' =>$id,
));
```